# How to fix "Syntax error - Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled" without babel

Tags: node.js, typescript, babeljs, next.js, nestjs

I created a test project here: https://github.com/baleksandr48/babel-question

Shortly: I created NextJS application and want to use pages/* files for rendering pages, and pages/api/[...catchAll].ts file for handling other requests. I decided to add NestJS - it allows me to divide the whole code on modules.

What is the problem: NestJS uses decorators and when I click button "get data" I have an error:

> Syntax error - Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled

I googled a little and solved this problem by adding ***.babelrc*** file:

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }]
  ]
}
```

But I wonder the question could I solve it without babel?
When I delete `.babelrc` file and run command `ts-node backend/main.ts` my application works without error.

Why? Am I right that when I run backend separately I transpiles typescript to es5 (as I set in `tsconfig.json`) and node works fine with es5.
But when I run the app with `npm run dev` then what?

- Isn't code been transpiled to es5?
- isn't everything what I have in `pages/api` been executed only on the backend side via node, but not via browser?
- if code been executed in browser, isn't browser works fine with es5?

Please describe me what is the difference between initialising backend app through `npm run dev` and `ts-node backend/main.ts` ?

Comment: can you share us your solution?

Comment: @softmarshmallow I still have no answer